# "Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil" while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, fatal-error

I built an animated button on the entry screen and tried to make the animated button a storyboard seque to but **I keep getting this error (`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil` while unwrapping an Optional value) after it crashes.**

Here is my code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  MyChapel
//
//  Created by Kamau Exom on 6/10/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 SevenCreative. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var LoginLogoReveal: LogoRevealView!
    @IBOutlet weak var PhotosFade: PhotosFadeView!
    @IBOutlet weak var LoginBG: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var LoginLogo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var LoginButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var SignupButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var LoginScreen: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        LoginLogoReveal.addRevealAnimation()
        PhotosFade.addPhotoFadeAnimation()

        self.LoginLogoReveal.alpha = 1.0

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 2.0, options: nil, animations: { self.LoginLogoReveal.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)

        self.PhotosFade.alpha = 0

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 2.5, options: nil, animations: { self.PhotosFade.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)

        self.LoginBG.alpha = 0

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 2.0, options: nil, animations: { self.LoginBG.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)


        self.LoginLogo.alpha = 0

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 2.5, options: nil, animations: { self.LoginLogo.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)

        self.LoginButton.alpha = 0

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 3.0, options: nil, animations: { self.LoginButton.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)

        self.SignupButton.alpha = 0

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 3.5, options: nil, animations: { self.SignupButton.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)


        let loginurl = NSURL(string: "http://www.mychapel.net/?memberful_endpoint=auth")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: loginurl!)

        LoginScreen?.scalesPageToFit = true
        LoginScreen?.loadRequest(request)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

The error appears at "`LoginLogoReveal.addRevealAnimation()`"

Comment: Are you certain you've wired up the outlet in Interface Builder?

Comment: LoginLogoReveal is nil. Most likely it's not wired up in the IB. Also by convention all instance variables starts with lower case letter.

Comment: Where is your function addRevealAnimation the error is probably inside it

Comment: ![Error Screenshot](http://5788a91c4555d8469b20-f1e6194a1935efa2860a09f8ff6beb1c.r20.cf1.rackcdn.com/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-11%20at%203.07.29%20PM.png).

Comment: I found the answer, I need to create another swift for the next page. I was trying to do everything from the "Main" swift file.